# Vue-cli-3 "npm run build/watch": I want the same outputDir for WordPress theme

Tags: webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to get the same `outputDir` (and `publicPath`) for the 
`npm run build`
and 
`npm run watch`
commands.

I'm trying to use vue-cli to create components that I can use within my WordPress Theme. My theme will pass the components the data they need via props. So, it would be **most convenient** if I could use npm run watch to build the various components and then have them output to the `/wp-content/themes/mytheme/js` folder so that all I have to do is hit refresh when I change something in the Vue component.

So far, I have this in `vue.config.js` but it only works with `npm run build` and it includes all the various other stuff for an SPA which I *don't want*.

```
// vue.config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/wp-content/themes/wvd/dist/',
    outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../dist"),
    filenameHashing: false,
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.optimization.delete('splitChunks')
    }
}
```

is there any way to configure this, so that I can have just that `app.js` and `app.css` in the `...../dist` folder without all the other SPA stuff for both `npm run build` and `npm run watch`?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SO what I ended up doing a while back was to add to `package.json`

```
{
  ...,
  scripts: {
    ...,
    'watch' : 'vue-cli-service build --watch --inline-vue',
    ...,
  }
}
```

while using the following settings in `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  'publicPath': '/wp-content/themes/my_theme/dist/js',
  'outputDir': '../dist',
  'filenameHashing': false,
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  'css': {
    extract: true,
  },
}
```

Thought I'd update this here just in case someone was trying to do the same.